# Do introverts tend to experience more psychological problems?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, personality

Are there any evidence suggesting that the more introvert people could be more subject to psychological problems?

Is possible to hypothesize that one of the causes is the lack of ideas in comparison with other people from the community?

Comment: Introversion is one of the risk factors for anorexia, i.e. anorectic patients are more likely to be introverted than the average person. I don't know if other disorders correlate with introversion.

Comment: They seem to relate, but I think it's important to note that this is not an inherent relation. All of these may simply root in the fact that the western business world orbits around extrovert's needs. How many times has it been deemed asocial if that "geek" guy refuses to take part in social lunching? Open floors? Team events? All these things drain energy and may lead to wrong self-perceptions, and ultimately to severe conditions. Would there be acceptance and respect for the introvert half (like introverts accept and respect extravert behaviour), these conditions would maybe not manifest.1/2

Comment: Likewise, forcing extroverts into introvert worlds may lead to conditions for the extrovert. If you have an inherent need to talk all day, but nobody in the room shares that need, you might be in for these conditions, too. (NOTE: I am not turning this into an answer as I don't have the asked-for evidence) 2/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several other disorders relate to introversion, including:

- Avoidant personality disorder <sup>(Morey et al., 2002)</sup>
- Obsessive-compulsive disorder <sup>([Samuels et al., 2000](http://bjp.rcpsych.org/content/177/5/457.long))</sup>
- Schizotypal personality disorder <sup>(Funder, 1997? Don't have it on-hand, but will try to verify this later when I do.)</sup>
- Schizoid personality disorder <sup>(Morey et al., 2002)</sup>
- Generalized anxiety disorder in young adults (ages 25–39; <sup>Kessler et al., 2008)</sup>

I would not expect lack of ideas to mediate these relationships. Introversion is sometimes thought to relate to "richer inner worlds" (can't recall where I read that, and I don't put a lot of stock in the claim). Introversion relates negatively to openness to experience, but seems to have a complex relationship with creativity. A common theory about introversion is that it relates to interest in reading (found some such evidence in Chinese adolescents so far; <sup>Lau & Cheung, 1988);</sup> this would certainly help with any lack of ideas.

<sup>**References**

- Funder, D. C. (1997). *The personality puzzle*. W. W. Norton & Co.

- Kessler, R. C., Gruber, M., Hettema, J. M., Hwang, I., Sampson, N., & Yonkers, K. A. (2008).  Comorbid major depression and generalized anxiety disorders in the National Comorbidity Survey follow-up.  *Psychological Medicine, 38*(3), 365–374.

- Lau, S., & Cheung, S. M. (1988). Reading interests of Chinese adolescents: Effects of personal and social factors. *International Journal of Psychology, 23*(1-6), 695–705.

- Morey, L. C., Gunderson, J. G., Quigley, B. D., Shea, M. T., Skodol, A. E., McGlashan, T. H., ... & Zanarini, M. C. (2002). The representation of borderline, avoidant, obsessive-compulsive, and schizotypal personality disorders by the five-factor model. *Journal of Personality Disorders, 16*(3), 215–234.

- Samuels, J., Nestadt, G., Bienvenu, O. J., Costa, P. T., Riddle, M. A., Liang, K. Y., ... & Cullen, B. (2000). Personality disorders and normal personality dimensions in obsessive—compulsive disorder. *The British Journal of Psychiatry, 177*(5), 457–462. Retrieved from http://bjp.rcpsych.org/content/177/5/457.long.</sup>

Comment: They seem to relate, but I think it's important to note that this is not an inherent relation. All of these may simply root in the fact that the western business world orbits around extrovert's needs. How many times has it been deemed asocial if that "geek" guy refuses to take part in social lunching? Open floors? Team events? All these things drain energy and may lead to wrong self-perceptions, and ultimately to severe conditions. Would there be acceptance and respect for the introvert half (like introverts accept and respect extravert behaviour), these conditions would maybe not manifest.

Comment: Likewise, forcing extroverts into introvert worlds may lead to conditions for the extrovert. If you have an inherent need to talk all day, but nobody in the room shares that need, you might be in for these conditions, too.